# How to pass an array / model object to master layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created a xml file (layout.xml) to render its contents to layout page,

Action LoadPage is used to deserialize this xml.

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel));

string path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/LayoutConfig/layout.xml"));

var arrList = (MyModel)ser.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(path));
```

How to pass arrList to mvc master layout page.

I've tried setting `ViewBag.Data = arrList;` it works only for that particular controller action 
I know ViewBag is actually just a wrapper around the ViewData object, and its purpose is to use dynamics to access the data instead of using magic strings

And i tried a dirty hack i.e `@Html.Action("LoadPage","Main")` to the master layot page and its not worked for me..

My question is it possible to get arrList in master layout page on each time it is called.

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you have in every View this key on `ViewBag` you could read on the Layout page., you could create your own base controller that inherits from `Controller` class and override the `OnActionExecuting` method, to fill this property on the ViewBag. In your controllers you should inherit from this custom base controller and you would get in all Views this Key on the ViewBag such as the asp.net mvc does with `Title` property on the ViewBag. For sample:

```
public class InfoController : Controller 
{   
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel));
        string path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/LayoutConfig/layout.xml"));
        var arrList = (MyModel)ser.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(path));

        ViewBag.ArrayInfo = arrList;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And in the other controllers:

```
public class HomeController : InfoController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```